# Issue sending cropped image via http in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I am using [Angular Croppie](https://github.com/lpsBetty/angular-croppie) and I am having an issue sending the cropped image the user provides via http. A user uploads an image:

```
<input data-upload-directive type="file" name="file" accept="image/*" />
```

Which is available to edit by the user via the `croppie` directive:

```
<croppie ng-if="cropped.source" src="cropped.source"
         ng-model="cropped.image"
         options="{boundary:{width:300,height:350}}">
</croppie>
```

And I access the file data via a custom directive:

```
function uploadDiretive(uploadAvatarServ) {

return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        element.bind('change', function (event) {

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
               scope.$apply(function () {
                   scope.cropped.source = e.target.result; //THIS IS THE CROPPED IMAGE
               });
               var formData = new FormData();
               formData.append('file', element[0].files[0]);

               uploadAvatarServ('../p3sweb/FileUploadServlet', formData, function (callback) {
                   console.log(callback)
                });

            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        });
    }
};
```

Sending `element[0].files[0]` works, however, that sends the original image which I don't want. I want the cropped image which is created in the front-end via the `croppie` directive.

```
<croppie ng-if="cropped.source" src="cropped.source"
         ng-model="cropped.image"
         options="{boundary:{width:300,height:350}}">
</croppie>
```

You can see I target the cropped image with the event paramater in `reader.onload`.

**Question**

How do I send the cropped image (`scope.cropped.source = e.target.result`) in an http request? Note: when I log `e.target.result` it shows a Base64 URL

Comment: You got a BASE64 URL because the code asked for a BASE64 URL. What did you think was going to happen when it invoked [reader.readAsDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)?

Comment: Well with the original file it does actually successfully make the `http` request. The code above shows the original file being uploaded successfully, I was just wondering how to send the cropped image which is stored in `scope.cropped.source`